# Outlook 2010 addin tab for several ribbon types

Tags: c#, outlook, ribbon-control

I want my tab to be shown on several ribbon types in Outlook 2010:
Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose, 
Microsoft.Outlook.Post.Compose, 
Microsoft.Outlook.Response.Compose, 
Microsoft.Outlook.Sharing.Compose.

Currently it's shown only on Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose though I selected all types above in designer.

What else I should do to apply me tab for all these ribbons?

And I've just noticed that my tab is not appear if I'm creating new rich text message (Email message using -> Rich text). Why?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the OfficeRibbon type properties:

[image]